# Google Spreadsheet =query - ignore entities where cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

my starting table looks similar to the following

```
Person 1, 75
Person 2, 48 
Person 3,
Person 4, 82
Person 5,
Person 6, 93 
...
```

I now try to include in following query a "where" statement to exclude entities that have no numeric value. This is what I currently have to show me the lowest 5 values of the set above and it works so far

```
=QUERY('DPS Transpose Tables'!D1:E29;"select D, max(E) group by D order by max(E) asc limit 5 label max(E)  ''";0)
```

How can I add something like this that works

```
=QUERY('DPS Transpose Tables'!D1:E29;"select D  where (E<>"" OR Is not NULL), max(E) group by D order by max(E) asc limit 5 label max(E)  ''";0)
```

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 'where E >=0' like this:

```
=QUERY('DPS Transpose Tables'!D1:E29,"select D, max(E) where E >=0 group by D order by max(E) asc limit 5 label max(E)  ''",0)
```

Comment: Hi @Ed Nelson, awesome! Works perfectly, you saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try 'WHERE IS NOT NULL'

Sometimes I find using the >= 0 does not get the desired results

`=QUERY('DPS Transpose Tables'!D1:E29,"select D, max(E) where E IS NOT NULL group by D order by max(E) asc limit 5 label max(E)  ''",0)`

Answer (score 0):

---

### Use NOT Equal To and '' empty string with single '' combination

**Where E <> ''**